# Deploying Express JS Server With Functions That Use Selenium WebDriver

Tags: node.js, selenium, express, deployment, selenium-chromedriver

I am a building an Express JS Server where some (at least 1) route uses Selenium to perform specific actions on another website in a browser. For example, I have a route: **mywebsite.com/api/login** that route should open a Selenium instance on Google Chrome that logs in to a specific website (e.g. anotherwebsite.com).
What is the best way to achieve this and which method or service can provide such service for Free for development and/or cheap. As well as being cheap for production.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can develop own your own machine for free. Either Express.js or Selenium is FOSS. To host for production you can find any Linux VPS provider that runs Node.js. DigitalOcean, Vultr or Linode would be the more affordable option.